Start-Process with -WindowStyle Minimized does not work on Win11
I upgraded from win10 to win11 and a Powershell script that I have that opens shares does not work any longer, which worked every time in win10. It seems to only do this behavior with network shares. The code snippet that isn't working is
Start-Process "\\share\directory\" -WindowStyle Minimized;
For some reason the minimization does not function properly, the window will instead be located off of screen and restoring it places it off of screen?
Is this a known issue? Below is how the taskbar appears



You appear to have it a bug (which on my machine also affects local paths); a workaround is to use the Shell.Application COM object's .ShellExecute() method:
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).ShellExecute(
  '\\share\directory\', 
  $null,  # args to pass; N/A here
  $null,  # working dir; N/A here
  $null,  # the shell operation (verb); use default ('Open')
  7       # show minimized (see below)
)

Note:

As with your Start-Process -WindowStyle Minimized approach, the newly opened window receives the  input focus, despite being minimized.

While the 7 value (see the list of supported window-style constants should not give the newly launched window focus, this is in effect ignored for File Explorer windows (that is, it behaves as if 2 had been specified).

To avoid this behavior would require another workaround: reactivate the PowerShell window after launching the window; while
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate($PID) does that in principle, programmatic activation of a window that is then not the active window is prevented by default, and allowing it requires a P/Invoke call, as demonstrated in this answer.




Thanks for the reply, I altered my code to use this method and the issue is still occurring although now it occurs for about half of the shares that are being opened (4 out of 8).

Interesting, @Bbb - I cannot get it to fail, but there are not many shares I can test with. I wonder if there's a timing issue when you first access a given share and whether running something like $null  = Get-Item '\\share\directory\' first makes a difference.

That's a good point, I have added Sleep -Seconds 1 in between each share open and will report back how that works. If it doesn't, I'll try the Get-Item as well

Technically you are not starting a process, you are forcing Windows to make an election based on "type association" in this case the type is a UNC path which should run explorer, but by that time it's ignored the minimized preference.
What if you try this?
Start-Process explorer.exe -ArgumentList "\\share\directory\" -WindowStyle Minimized;

It worked for me, but then I could never "restore" or view the window. That may be what you want but I'm not sure what you're trying to do.
UPDATE: While waiting for stack overflow's 30 minute rule I did eventually see that it showed the explorer window in a 2 inch square unusual size. The point is to manipulate the window behavior you have to actually call an executable where the window size can be manipulated.

Your suggested command has the same effect as the command in the question, so it cannot be expected to make a difference.

Thanks for the reply, the behavior is the same unfortunately
